# How can I create software for multiple mobile platforms?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7

If I created a piece of software for Windows phone, for example using C#, and I want to publish this software on other platforms (iPhone or Android), do I have to rewrite the code in Java for Android and in Objective-C for the iPhone? Or are there other solutions?

Comment: The short answer is yes you'd have to rewrite the code for each native platform. Another option you have is to build your app using web technologies (HTML/CSS/Javascript) and then you can use phonegap(or one of a handful of others) to spit out a bare bones native "wrapper" app for several different platforms.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a C# programmer, you should look into mono/xamarin.
[Xamarin WebSite](http://xamarin.com/)

You can use Monotouch for iPhone Development and Monodroid for Android.

You should be aware that you will still need to know how to build the user interface using the native SDK components.

Comment: And http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

I like Phonegap/Cordova. Allows you to use web technologies (Javascript, HTML, CSS) but package them up as apps for multiple platforms.